# How to export data like user id of users who installed my app by viewing ad using google adwords? I want to export it to big query if possible

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I have started a campaign on google adwords for my app. I want to see the result of this campaign. ie Which users are there in my database who installed my app after seeing ad on google adwords? And i want to see their behaviour ie how they performed after installing my app. Weather they registered or not and performed transaction or not.

I think i can achieve this if i got to know the user ids(corresponding to my database) of those users and see their performance in my database

My Approach:- I have integrated google analytics in my app and send user id (corresponding to my database) to GA while recording the events. I can see those user ids in GA report which have registered through Google Adwords.  I want to import these ids to big query table if possible.

Pls help.
Thanku

Comment: If you want to export to big query then I am going to assume you have a premium google analytics account.    I think you should contact your account manager they will help you export your data to big query.  Its what you are paying for really.

Comment: I m not using google analytics premium account. Is there any way to do without premium account? Or any other approach possible to get my database user ids from google adwords?

Comment: Only Google analytics premium customers have access to export data to Big Query no there is no other way.

Comment: Can i export data as other data format if possible? I can upload it to big query manually

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a Google analytics premium account, you'll have to do build something yourself.

Have a look at:

http://www.apirise.com/load-data-from-google-adwords-to-google-bigquery/
http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2016/02/new-solutions-in-adwords-scripts.html
https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/bigquery-exporter
https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/examples/google-bigquery